# file created using getRealPath gets created on .metada/.plugins folder not in WebContent project folder

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee

I am trying to create a file using below code in a `Servlet`:

```
File outfile= new File(servletContext.getRealPath("/Output/output.xml"));
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
```

from a J2EE Application (CallMain) and the file gets created in deployed temp path

*.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\CallMain\Output*

Actually I want the file to be created in current project folder: *WebContent*.

Comment: try this `File file = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/Output/output.xml"));`

Comment: Thx,But same results !

Comment: you have the output folder created under webapp?

Comment: Yes WebContent/Output.

Comment: Hey try like this getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"Output/output.xml";

Comment: It still remains with .metadata dir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually when you ran the servlet within eclipse using the embedded tomcat server

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF")
```

Gives you this

```
D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\DynaServletProject\WEB-INF
```

But when you ran the servlet from standalone Apache Tomcat:

```
getServletContext().getRealPath("WEB-INF")
```

This gives you

```
D:\apache-tomcat-7.0.33\webapps\DynaServletProject\WEB-INF
```

While in eclipse you can give the absolute path i dont think this is the best approach though

Answer (score 0):

By default, your application stages and runs from a directory buried in the workspace's .metadata directory. That *is* the "real path" at runtime. Check your Server's configuration for options regarding deploying the app directory from the workspace folders.